# how to wrap divs with their own children

Tags: jquery

I'm making a slideshow and some images need to be wrapped with a link and some don't. Right now I have it set up so if the image has a link it's hidden in a div below the image. So, I thought I could just take the link and wrap it around the image with jquery. I found this bit of code that got me really close:

```
$(".views-field-field-banner-image").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).next().find("a").attr("href"); 
    return false;
});
```

The problem is that if the image doesn't have a link i can still click on it and get an error: 'undefined'.

Hope someone has seen this before. Any advice helps! Thanks.

Comment: Can you just add `a ` (with a space) before your selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about putting a simple validation:

```
$(".views-field-field-banner-image").click(function() {
    if($(this).next().find("a").attr("href").length)
         window.location = $(this).next().find("a").attr("href"); 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This worked perfect, Thanks! Would it be easy to add a class here too so I can control with css which one shows a pointer on hover?

Comment: how about: `$(this).next().find("a").addClass('classname')`